# Sobolev embeddings for fractional order spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

In Adams and Fournier (1) Theorem 4.12 they present a very comprehensive collection of embedding results for Sobolev spaces of integer orders. From results such as Theorem 5.1 in Amann (2) ([see answer here for summary of the theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259579/fractional-order-rellich-kondrashov-theorem)) it would appear that at least some of these embedding results generalizes to fractional order Sobolev spaces. Is it known if all the embedding results generalize to fractional order Sobolev spaces*), and if so, is there a nice comprehensive reference like in Adams and Fournier available, that someone could refer me to?

*) That is, (in case you have the book available), can we in general obtain the same results but for $ j\geq 0 $ and $ m\geq 1 $ in the theorem chosen as reals?

---

(1) [Adams & Fournier, Sobolev Spaces](https://books.google.dk/books/about/Sobolev_Spaces.html?id=R5A65Koh-EoC)
(2) Amann, Herbert. Compact embeddings of vector-valued Sobolev and Besov spaces. Dedicated to the memory of Branko Najman. Glas. Mat. Ser. III 35(55) (2000), no. 1, 161--177. MR1783238

Comment: What about the "Hitchhiker's guide to fractional Sobolev spaces" https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345?

Comment: Adams wrote [another book](http://ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=TI&pg7=MR&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Adams&s5=&s6=Sobolev%20spaces&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=6&mx-pid=450957) with some fractional Sobolev spaces in it.